# How to use Twilio Java SDK pagination for getting paginated Tasks?

Tags: java, kotlin, sdk, twilio

What I'm currently doing is fetching Tasks like:

```
val tasks = Task.reader(workspaceSid)
            .limit(10)
            .read()
```

What I'm getting is a `ResourceSet` containing a `Page<Task>` object. Inside `Page` there are `records` & the URLs for next and previous pages.

How to obtain these? There's no getter for the page, so I cannot do

```
result.getPage().getNextPageUrl()
```

Or maybe there's another way to use pagination?

Answer (score 0):

The library actually handles the pagination for you. [From the docs on the Java library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java#iterate-through-records):

> The library automatically handles paging for you. With the `read` method, you can specify the number of records you want to receive (`limit`) and the maximum size you want each page fetch to be (`pageSize`). The library will then handle the task for you, fetching new pages under the hood as you iterate over the records.